# react native how to animate scroll position and element height together

Tags: listview, animation, scrollview, react-native

I am using a react native list which will expand the list elements to full height.

Assuming list offset is 'o' and viewport height is 'H' and element pos is 'py' and element height 'h'.

This involves two steps:

1. Scroll the list view to desired offset: o -> o + py
2. Resize the element height:  h -> H

I want to be able to animate these two properties simultaneously but without flicker.

The current approach which I am using is

```
lisview.scrollTo({y: o + py}, {animated: true})
var mh = new Animated.Value(h);
this.setState({height: mh});
Animated.timing(mh, {toValue: H}).start();
```

But the animation is not smooth. I would like to know the best way to animate the scroll and height at the same time. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Animations can sometimes appear janky in the simulator but nice and smooth on a device.  Have you tried both?

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, but I hope the answer can help others.

I just had the same problem. One can't easily control the scroll animation, since it is done in native code. I can't say I've found a wonderful solution, but it's working for me.

What I did was to decrease the animation duration and add a delay. It resulted in a similar UX. The code goes like:

```
lisview.scrollTo({y: o + py, animated: true})
var mh = new Animated.Value(h);
this.setState({height: mh});
// Default animation duration is 500, so it will be a little faster
Animated.timing(mh, {toValue: H, duration: 100, delay: 300}).start();
```

The final effect was to see the scrolling to position and also see the end of the height animation without any glitch. Tested with many different heights.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parallel`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#parallel) to start an array of animations at the same time. There's a good guide to animations [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#composing-animations), including parallel animations.

Comment: which scrollview property would you animate with parallel animations. I tried to call scrollTo but doesn't work smoothly. Can you give code example?